# How to turn two LED's on and off with one button?

Tags: led, button

I was wondering how to write a code that would do this, WITHOUT using IF and ELSE: when the button is pressed, one LED is on and the other one is off, but when the button is not pressed, the LED that was on turns off and the other one turns on.

Comment: Other than with the `!` operator?

Comment: Commenting instead of replying because you asked for code, but this could be done in hardware.  If you wire in a PNP transistor to switch the second LED, it will free up the second DIO pin.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use `if` and `else`?  Is this just hypothetical fun?

Comment: @KJP if you add an x amount of shift registers, you'll free up an (x*8)-6 amount of in/outputs? ;D

Answer (score 7):

Just use the return value of `digitalRead` (which is 1 or 0) as the input to `digitalWrite`:

```
int btnVal = digitalRead(3);
digitalWrite(4, btnVal);      // On when button is HIGH
digitalWrite(5, 1 - btnVal);  // Off when button is HIGH
```

Or using boolean instead:

```
bool btnVal = digitalRead(3);
digitalWrite(4, btnVal);      // On when button is HIGH
digitalWrite(5, !btnVal);     // Off when button is HIGH
```

Comment: You can also use `!` with `int` values.

Comment: You don't say....

Comment: Wasn't necessarily telling that to you, but leaving that comment as a note to the OP, which seems to be a beginner, or to any future reader.

Comment: in C, `bool` and `int` are interchangeable.

Comment: There is no such thing as bool in C.

Comment: @Majenko: In C99 there is `_Bool`, and `bool` if you `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet It may be called a _Bool but it's still an integer: `Boolean values still behave as integers, can be stored in integer variables, and used anywhere integers would be valid, including in indexing, arithmetic, parsing, and formatting. This approach ("Boolean values are just integers") has been retained in all later versions of C.`

Comment: Yes, C bools are integers, yet `(bool) 1 == (bool) 2`.

Comment: And also `(1 != 0) == (2 != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with only a `switch`/`case` statement. You do not even need to de-bounce the switch.